# Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity in ASP .NET - is it safe to use

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpcontext

Inside my AuthenticateRequest event handler I set Thread's principal. Here'a a part of my IHttpModule:

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += AuthenticateRequest;
    }

    private void AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var principal = CreatePrincipal();
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
```

But I have an assembly, that should not have access to System.Web, so I cannot use HttpContext.Current.User, but I need to access current principal. My very first thought was to change my method to:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

and use Thread.CurrentPrincipal when needed.

But as far as I remember it is not safe to store request specific stuff in Thread Local Storage as multiple threads can handle the same request, so I guess it is the same with **Thread.CurrentPrincipal**. Or not?

Comment: It sounds like you can change the assembly - is it not possible to pass it the principal it needs to work against?

Comment: In a similar situation recently I simply forced the caller to provide the principal object.

Comment: That's what I'll do - injecting principal. Anyway I was hoping that there's a better approach

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I disagree with Jeff Moser's answer.

The standard .NET authorization stuff all works using Thread.CurrentPrincipal. e.g.:

```
PrincipalPermissionAttribute
PrincipalPermission.Demand
```

Also, if you configure a .NET RoleProvider, it will set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to the same principal as `HttpContext.User`.

Therefore this is the standard way to do it, and I would do the same thing in your custom authentication code (or even better - implement it as a custom RoleProvider).

As for asynchronous I/O, [this blog post](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/ASPNETThreadSwitching.aspx) states that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and culture settings are automatically passed to the new thread.

Using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is arguably more secure, if your library is using the principal for authorization purposes, because untrusted code can pass in a principal as an argument, while CAS might prevent it from setting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't realize ASP.NET did that for you. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Well actually it makes sense. I use authorization attributes like PrincipalPermission all over the application, and apparently these attributes use Thread.CurrentPrincipal behind the scenes. Thanks a lot!